# is there a way to make a drawing game on python turtle with two turtles at the same time, where they cant touch the lines?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

You see, I have a drawing program but, I would like to know if there is:
1) A way too use two turtles at the same time.
And...
2)If there was a way you could make the program shut turtle graphics and present the winner after someone has touched a line.
a bit like Tron when you cant touch the lines because you die from them

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you have tried? maybe some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can make 2 instances of turtle's Turtle class:

```
import turtle 
foo = turtle.Turtle()
bar = turtle.Turtle()

foo.forward(100)
bar.left(90)
```

2) Theoretically possible as you can get the turtle's position with turtle.pos(), so you could record the turns and use that to calculate the whole path. However you could end up with very large data structures for collision detection quite quickly. Might be beter to adapt a Snake game instead.